# How do the Weird Sisters' Instruments Work?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, music

[This picture](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/8/87/WeirdSisters.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141208020843), which I found on the Harry Potter wiki, is of the Weird Sisters, the wizarding band from the Yule Ball.  In the picture, you can see that one of them at least is playing what seems to be an electric guitar.  Indon't know what all of their instruments are, but they look exactly like a Muggle band, including their electric guitars and maybe other stuff.  But everyone knows that, 
1) Wizards are clueless to Muggle technology (I myself don't even know what electri--I mean, Arthur Weasley), and
2) Muggle technology doesn't work on the Hogwarts grounds.

Note: this is mostly about the movies, since I found this passage in the books:

> A set of drums, several guitars, a lute, a cello, and some bagpipes were upon it [the stage]

Comment: I'm going with "magic"

Comment: You know, I thought about that.  But I realized that 1) it's a boring answer, and 2) there is NO reason WHATSOEVER for me to know ANYTHING about magic.  Eclecticity, that's what I know

Comment: @Richard -- Ooo, you just utilized the "Because, magic" clause of The Many Tropes (Memes) of SFF! :D

Comment: Richard is correct -- the answer is, actually, "Because, magic"! :)

Comment: Don't you guys think i would know if it were ma--if it weren't eclectiricity (I spelled it right this time)?  After all, I'm an expert

Comment: are you sure that ALL Muggle technology doesn't work on Hogwarts grounds? Not saying you're wrong, I just seem to (vaguely) remember it being mainly "advanced" technology that didn't work, such as GPS navigation tools or a computer. The reason it wouldn't work was because of the unplottable nature of Hogwarts, not because of some "anti-tech" enchantment _per se_.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's all, like, elrctisitty and stuff.